# error al ejecutar robocopy con espacios y guiones

Tags: windows, cmd

Tengo un archivo bat que contiene lo siguiente:

```
SET ORGN= "C:\ProgramData\Circutor\PowerStudio Scada\Data\"
Set DEST= "C:\Users\Administrador\OneDrive - MiDominio\CopiaCircutor\"


robocopy.exe %ORGN% %DEST% /E
```

De esta forma copiaré los cambios en onedrive y se sincronizará, sin embargo al ejecutar me da error:

> ```
>   Origen - C:\ProgramData\Circutor\PowerStudio Scada\Data"  C:\Users\Administrador\OneDrive\
>     Destino -
>
>    Archivos:
>  Opciones: /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ERROR: parámetro no válido nº2 : "-"
>
>       Uso sencillo :: ROBOCOPY origen destino /MIR
>
>             origen :: Directorio de origen (unidad:\ruta o
>                       \\servidor\recurso_compartido\ruta).
>            destino :: Directorio de destino  (unidad:\ruta o
>                       \\servidor\recurso_compartido\ruta).
>               /MIR :: Reflejar un árbol de directorios completo.
>
>    Para obtener más información de uso, ejecute ROBOCOPY /?
> ```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Gracias.

Comment: No es necesario poner dos comillas dobles como estas `""` en bat y tampoco robocopy lo necesita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debería solucionarse si colocas el segundo `SET` en una nueva línea y eliminas el último slash \ a ambos directorios de esta manera:

```
SET ORGN= "C:\ProgramData\Circutor\PowerStudio Scada\Data"
SET DEST= "C:\Users\Administrador\OneDrive - MiDominio\CopiaCircutor"

robocopy.exe %ORGN% %DEST% /E
```

Debido a que escribiste todo en una línea la variable DEST recibía un valor equivocado.

---

Si por alguna razón no te funciona después de hacer esos cambios, puedes añadir `pause` al final de tu archivo bat para que no se cierre al terminar y puedas copiar el error que sale para con el actualizar la pregunta.

---

Hice un test con este código en Windows 10:

```
SET ORGN= "C:\ProgramData\Circutor\PowerStudio Scada\Data"
SET DEST= "C:\Users\Ariel Montes\OneDrive\CopiaCircutor\Test - comilla y espacios"

robocopy.exe %ORGN% %DEST% /E

pause
```

Y el archivo se copió y obtuve este resultado en el cmd (disculpa que está en italiano):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Copia di file efficace per Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Avviato: giovedì 17 dicembre 2020 05:31:07 PM
      Origine : C:\ProgramData\Circutor\PowerStudio Scada\Data\
 Destinazione : C:\Users\Ariel Montes\OneDrive\CopiaCircutor\Test - comilla y espacios\

         File: *.*

      Opzioni: *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           1    C:\ProgramData\Circutor\PowerStudio Scada\Data\
            Nuovo file                 0        test.txt

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

              Totale   Copiato  IgnorateNon corrispondentiNon riuscitaSupplementari
Directory:         1         0         1         0         0         0
     File:         1         1         0         0         0         0
     Byte:         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Durata:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Terminato: giovedì 17 dicembre 2020 05:31:07 PM
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: acabo de hacer una prueba, en el destino he borrado una carpeta enorme y he ejecutado el fichero con la siguiente configuracion

SET ORGN= "C:\ProgramData\Circutor\PowerStudio Scada\Data" 

SET DEST= "C:\Users\Administrador\OneDrive - MiDominio\CopiaCircutor"


robocopy.exe %ORGN% %DEST% /E

sin embargo no se ha copiado nada

Directorios: 29 0 0 0 0 0 Archivos: 2607 44 2563 0 0 1 Bytes: 9.052 g 110.35 m 8.945 g 0 0 0 Veces: 0:00:00 0:00:00 0:00:00 0:00:00

Velocidad: 820642021 Bytes/s Velocidad: 46957.513 Megabytes/min Finalizado: jueves, 17 de diciembre de 2020 17:05:50

Comment: los dos set estan separados por ENTER, hay una linea en blanco

Comment: te lo agradezco, es una tonteria, pero me serviria porque ese bat irá en una tarea programada y subira la copia al cloud

Comment: Me parece que por el output que mandaste en el comentario si está copiando archivos. No entiendo que problema tienes. Con el test que hice pude copiar un archivo sin problemas

Comment: yo borre una carpeta en destino y vuelvo a ejecutar la instruccion para que la copie y no aparece en destino

Comment: Eso no debería pasar, pero creo que es material para una pregunta diferente. Ahora ya se resolvió el tema principal de esta pregunta sobre los directorios que no funcionaban.

He echo pruebas con carpetas, archivos  y subcarpetas y todo funciona correctamente. 

Si te parece bien abre una nueva pregunta con el problema y lo que te devuelve el código y veremos de ayudarte